# Trying to call class/method into main

Tags: java, class, methods, call

I am trying to run the contents from this class in my main class, however I cannot figure out a way to do this. I have tried different options from importing package.class and creating instances to other options. Does this have to do with the way this class is constructed. I just don't want to keep spinning my wheels if this isn't possible. Logic of the issue is greatly appreciated.

```
package stockapplication;


import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Database {

public int empNum;
public String empFirst;
public String empLast;
public int empSal;

public Database(int c, String a, String b, int s) {
    empNum = c;
    empFirst = a;
    empLast = b;
    empSal = s;
}

public int getEmpNum() {
    return empNum;
}

public String getEmpFirst() {
    return empFirst;
}

public String getEmpLast() {
    return empLast;
}

public int getSalary() {
    return empSal;

}

public static void Stock() {

    Database[] array = new Database[3];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.printf("Please enter your employee number:");
        int c = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.printf("Please enter employee first name:");
        String a = sc.next();
        System.out.printf("Please enter employee last name:");
        String b = sc.next();
        System.out.printf("Please enter your salary:");
        int s = sc.nextInt();
        array[i] = new Database(c, a, b, s);

        try {
            File f = new File("Database1.txt");
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(f, true));
            pw.append("\n" + c + "," + a + "," + b + "," + s + ",");
            pw.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `catch (Exception e) {
        }` never silently swallow exceptions - maybe there is some very important information there?

Comment: Also you do not have a `main` method showing in this code

Comment: You need to create an instance of this class by calling the constructor: `Database db = new Database(0, "foo", "bar", 1);`

Comment: @ScaryWombat My main class is in different tab in Netbeans. I found this code and tweaked it to fit my purpose. It originally had a main method in it, but I took it out. I wanted to bring this code into my main method as part of a larger project. I am ultimately trying to create a text database of stocks I can have the user manage. Maybe there is another way I need to structure the code. I haven't changed the stock info yet just wanted to see if I could get this working in main method. I had to educate myself on Exception e and found it is considered bad practice.

Comment: and what errors / problems are you facing?

Comment: Also `public static void Stock()` - why static?

Comment: @ScaryWombat   I am totally and utterly lost on where to start. I put static because I researched that I could call a method by just putting ClassName.method(); after I import the package.ClassName. I was just trying different things. I feel like I need to restart at this point. I was going to create an SQL Database to access from my program, but I am on a time crunch and thought trying to code it out might be less involved. So the problem I guess is I am trying to make it work by using this edited code and create a database out of it, and I am trying to learn as I go.

Comment: at the moment what you have is a class called `Database` which has a method called `Stock` which creates three instances of `Database`.  Maybe you do not need this method at all, and move the code from `Stock` to your `main`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Actually, that is a good idea. If I want to be able to manipulate the data later such as a user having option for multiple users to buy/sell stock, do you think that would create problems, or should I be able to reference the variables attached to the different stocks? If that makes since.

Comment: Yes you should separate input from storage.

Answer (score 0):

Add another class, where you will add your logic and keep your Database object as a model. Then, from your `Main` call this new class and run it's method.

```
public class ServiceDB {

    public ServiceDB() {
        //Empty
    }

    public void writeDB() {
        Database[] array = new Database[3];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Please enter your employee number:");
            int c = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.printf("Please enter employee first name:");
            String a = sc.next();
            System.out.printf("Please enter employee last name:");
            String b = sc.next();
            System.out.printf("Please enter your salary:");
            int s = sc.nextInt();
            array[i] = new Database(c, a, b, s);
            try {
                File f = new File("Database1.txt");
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(f, true));
                pw.append("\n" + c + "," + a + "," + b + "," + s + ",");
                pw.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Never a good idea to leave it empty, at least print the error.
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Main**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ServiceDB serviceDB = new ServiceDB();
    serviceDB.writeDB();
}
```

Of course, I am skipping the imports. If you need me to add them, let me know.